# Join COVP and GLPCA Tables

Tags: abap, opensql, sap-erp

this topic is rather cryptic for me cause I am no SAP/ABAP developer (SAP tables are for me just a datasource)

I have 2 tables COVP and GLPCA. I try to join them but I do not know on which key I can do that.

Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: `COVP` is not a table, it's a view comprising the tables `COEP` and `COBK`. I have no idea of the table usage though, so I won't be able to help you.

Comment: right, this is no table. What my customer actually tried is to get the SD information with link to profitcenters. If I understood well ProfitCenters are objects from CO, they do not have very much to do with SD objects. Goal would then be to join those 2 datasources.

Answer (score 1):

COVP is a View (Two already 'joined' tables, being COEP and COBK).

To join them my guess without having any data to look at is join using the following rules;

```
GLPCA-RCLNT = COVP-MANDT
GLPCA-DOCNR = COVP-BELNR
GLPCA-REFDOCLN = COVP-BUZEI
GLPCA-KOKRS = COVP-KOKRS
```

**EDIT:** Looking in our system we don't actually use GLPCA. Exactly what data is it you are wanting to display against each other? I will edit my answer accordingly as I do not understand your requirements at the moment reading your comments above. Cheers

Comment: thanks for your response ; the goal is actually to create a Sales report per ProfitCenter and Customer.

Problem : in the SD Tables (VBAK, VBAP) there are not all the sales bookings, some are missing.

therefore our idea was to get the COVP bookings and allocate them a profitcenter using the GLPCA table

thanks for the joining fields though, I'm gonna give it a try